# Is there a way to work with generic types on Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

Currently I'm working on an Android app which fetches for 18 types of different data references, but each of these references have its own reference class saved on Realm DB, as shown below.

There's the reference for Type A.

```
public class ReferenceTypeA implements RealmModel {

    @Expose @SerializedName("codReference")
    @PrimaryKey
    private String codReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("nameReference")
    private String nameReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("data")
    private TypeA data;
}
```

And there's the reference for TypeB.

```
public class ReferenceTypeB implements RealmModel {

    @Expose @SerializedName("codReference")
    @PrimaryKey
    private String codReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("nameReference")
    private String nameReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("data")
    private TypeB data;
}
```

Does Realm allow using a generic type, so I can use one Reference model and then cast `data` to each type of reference I'll use at the moment? Is the code below valid? Or should I use a JSON String and then cast the result?

```
public class Reference implements RealmModel {

    @Expose @SerializedName("codReference")
    @PrimaryKey
    private String codReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("nameReference")
    private String nameReference;

    @Expose @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cc @EpicPandaForce

Comment: No, inheritance of fields across RealmObjects and polymorphism of RealmObjects is not supported by Realm on any platforms. If it is necessary to support polymorphism, then single-table-by-discriminator-field approach (merging every table for every type) manually is the one thing you can do.